# Handling different length string features and prediction of these based on other features

Tags: machine-learning, r, feature-engineering, data-science-model, feature-map

I am currently working on a problem where the dataset contains 200+ features (Let's call them the **code features**, e.g no.of.loops, memoryInst, loadInst, etc  and **Flags** that are used to compile code that has such characteristics/code features)

The flags are represented as strings:

**This is just dummy data.**

```
snippet                 FlagsUsed                   no.of.loops   loadInst      memoryInst

1  Mergesort      " -a -b -c -d=10 -e -f =19  -c "    1              0             10

2  Bubblesort     " -a -c -f=230 "                    2              5             3

3  MatrixMulti     " -f=20 -z -f12 -f2f "             0              10            4
```

I need some help with how these flags should be represented in the data, I **have tried one-hot encoding and dummy_variable methods** but these methods have some disadvantage:

1) **One-hot encoding:** using this method, the no. features will become huge, there are 150+ flags and I creating a one hot vector for each one of them would result in 22500 feature which is not feasible.

```
   flag1    flag2    flag3  flag4
1  -a       -b       -c      NA
2  -c       -a       -b      -z
```

I would need to create long vectors for each of the above feature flag1, flag2.. flag4

2) **Dummy_variable method:** There are 200+ different types/levels/factors of these flags and dummy_variable method create a feature for each level/factor which is not feasible.

Also, the **flags can repeat** in a single string (1st snippet, -c repeats).

I am thinking of some clever hashing that would maintain information regarding the sequence of the flags and there value (toggle flag = 0/1, threshold flag = {lower, upper} ). But the **problem with hashing is**, I have to, in **future, predict these flags** using other features (code features) and if I hash these flags somehow I won't be able to reverse hash them.

I am thinking of some fixed size vector representation which could be reversed so that I can tell flag using a numeric or hex number.

Can anyone please guide me or put me in the right direction. Would be thankful!

Comment: Why is it that your initial representation won't work?  In other words, if you make all your flags one big string per observation, why would that not work?

Comment: Each of the flag in the string has an effect on the performance of compiler, so I cannot use the flags string as it is. Also, in future, I would like to predict flags based on the code features and for that, the algo needs to learn the effect of flags and their relation to code features, this is not possible if I use big flag strings, right? Therefre I need to represent flags in such a way that the algo can see what flags were used in what positions with what code features.

Comment: What are the possible combination to flag one

Comment: each of the flag1, flag2, flag3 can have upto 150 different flags, and could repeat

for example:

   flag1 flag2 flag3

1 -a      -b     -c

2 -b      -d     -e

3 -z       NA   NA

4 -a      -a     NA

5 -c      -d    -b

The text in comments is not formated so It if you could plz copy paste and format the data in this comment in editor.

Comment: Lets be simple and clear, tell me only about flag 1.  How many  combo's?

Comment: Okay,

flags is a column/feature that contains a list of flag strings separated by space. Now when I separate the flags into individual tokens/flag,  the flags column is replaced by new columns like flag1, flag2, flag3. now, flag1 can have up to 150 flags for different observations (Same goes for flag2, flag3 ...) 

So basically,
I am splitting flag feature into multiple features on space so that I know, fr each row, which flag was in which position in the flag string.

what do you mean by combo?

Comment: By combos, I mean to ask if flag 1 can have values 'a','b','c' then the unique values for flag 1 are 'a','b','c' and the complete column will have n observations consisting of some combination of 'a's,'b's, and 'c's .

Comment: for each row flag1 can have only one value , lets say -a. and there are 150 unique values that flag1 can have.  The same goes for flag1, flag2 and so on..

Comment: How many flag columns total?

Comment: because flag strings are of different length, the total number of flag columns are equal to the max length of flags in any of the flag string.

lets say,
row1 has flag string = '-a' and row 2 has flag string of 10 flags '-a -b ..' then for row1, flag1 will be -a but flag2 -to- flag10 will be NA

Comment: So what is the max number of columns?

Comment: for now, its 200 flag columns.
But I am trying to reduce the flag string length(some compiler optimization stuff), it could be reduced to just 50 flag columns (not sure yet)

Comment: How many actual observations do you have?

Comment: 10k observations in total.

Comment: So your input data has a size of [10000,204] ?

Comment: No, I have other features as well, the dimensions of the data are: [10000, 450]

Comment: Are the flags your target values?  Are you trying to predict the sequence of flags, while using them as input as well?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96378/discussion-on-question-by-obiii-handling-different-length-string-features-and-pr).

Comment: Can continue in chat if you like